# JS: Extracting specific text from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this ...

```
var str = "6 validation errors detected: Value '' at 'confirmationCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\S]+; Value '' at 'confirmationCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'password' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\S]+; Value at 'password' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 6; Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+; Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1";
```

I want to extract all the "unique" lines that start with the word ... "Value" ...

So expected output is ...

- Value '' at 'confirmationCode' failed to satisfy constraint
- Value at 'password' failed to satisfy constraint
- Value at 'username' failed to
  satisfy constraint

Here is what I have tried so far ...

```
var x = str.split("\;|\:")  // This is NOT working
console.log(x);

var z = y.filter(word => word.indexOf("Value") > -1) // Also this needs to be tweaked to filter unique values
console.log(z);
```

Performance is an issue, so I prefer the most optimized solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a single regular expression, no `split` or `filter` or loops or other tests needed:

```js
var str = "6 validation errors detected: Value '' at 'confirmationCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\S]+; Value '' at 'confirmationCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'password' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\S]+; Value at 'password' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 6; Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+; Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1";

console.log(
  str.match(/((^|Value)[^:]+)(?!.*\1)/g)
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to also get the opening line "6 validation errors detected" along with the "value" lines ?

Comment: See edit, just match the beginning of the string or `Value`